# CMUSphinx for web application

Tags: web-services, web, cmusphinx

I'm trying to create an speech reconigtion based web. Afer some searching, i found that cmusphinx is a library quite good for speech reconigtion application. And my problem is how can communicate between cmusphinx and web ?
Sorry if this is a silly question.

Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need a web framework to marshal web requests to the Java or C code, then you just need to implement required speech-to-text methods with CMUSphinx API.

Here is the JAX-RS tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

There are also more lightweight web service framework, for example [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for Ruby.

You can also study existing implementations of web service using CMUSphinx, for example

https://github.com/alumae/ruby-pocketsphinx-server

Read more about it [here](http://www.phon.ioc.ee/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=people%3atanel%3amain.en&cache=cache&media=people%3atanel%3asltu2012_paper.pdf).