# Is there any free an unlimited speech recognition service nowadays which allows to receive text from an audio file?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

The only possibility I have found is setting [CMUSphinx as a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119696/cmusphinx-for-web-application)

Google speech API is neither unlimited(1) nor [safe to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721436/google-speech-api).

ATT Speech to Text is [free](https://developer.att.com/pricing/details#pricingDetails-speech) but [the app keys expire after 90 days and must be renewed](https://developer.att.com/pricing/api-platform-environments)(2), and [a lower maximum number of transactions allowed per day](http://developer.att.com/support/faqs/att-developer-program-and-api-platform-faqs#difference-between-sandbox-and-production-realms)(3)

I think that setting CMUSphinx as a web server would take a long time, so it is wise to consider other options. Do you have some recommendation?

Note: we are using Android, but the Android API only allows to recognize audio from the microphone, not from an audio file.

---

1) When you [obtain a free key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832087/where-can-i-get-google-developer-key), you only get a quota of 50 calls to the service per day:

[image: cuota of Google speech]

2) I'm not sure if that means if we must compile our software again.

3) I didn't find what is that limit exactly

Comment: Beside being free CMUSphinx has other advantages, for example you might properly tune it to get a best possible resource usage as well as best accuracy for a given task.

Comment: SR engines (particularly web-based engines) tend to be heavy consumers of resources.  It's not at all surprising that companies don't want unthrottled access to their servers.  It's more surprising that they give you access *at all*.

Comment: AT&T do provide 1,000,000 transactions per month for free, so it will go a long way... https://developer.att.com/pricing/details#pricingDetails-speech

Comment: @brandall I wrote about the free basic access of AT&T. The premium access you suggest is: $99 / year + usage fees, where the first million of transactions are "free"